# How can i avoid cast numbers to booleans in C#?

Tags: c#, grasshopper

I am writing a component for grasshopper in c#. But went i pass a number through a boolean it give me a a false or a true value. How can i add a exception to this event. I only want to pass as parameter booleans types

Comment: can you post your existing code?

Comment: Can you please add some details, such as code? This question as it is is unusably vague.

Comment: You're usually better off asking questions to do with Grasshopper on the Grasshopper developer forum (grasshopper3d.com). There's very few people here who even know what GH is. The topic is on hold now so I can't post an answer either, but in short; you can't override the automatic data conversions in GH. It is possible to detect them after the fact and take appropriate action, but I don't have enough characters here to show you how.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean types in C# can only have `true` or `false` values. If you wish to pass a number as a parameter, define it as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout any code is hard to tell, but if your method must have `int` in its signature, you can "translate" to `result = value != 0`.
But why don't you just modify your signature to `bool` anyway?
If you want to, you may have both!

```
void method(int value) {
   bool result = value != 0;
   method(result);
}
void method(bool value) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I will try caverna. And as well i will post some code. As soon i am in the computer again.